# Calculating the Median and Mode

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to write a Python script that uses sqlite3 to calculate the average, median and mode.

It's going very well (average works perfectly), except it will only calculate the median correctly if there is an odd number of items:

```
def select_median(conn):
    print("Median")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTemp AS " +
                "SELECT columnC, columnF FROM myTable order by columnC, columnF")
    cur.execute("SELECT a.columnC, a.columnF FROM ( " +
                "SELECT columnC, rowid, columnF " +
                "FROM myTemp) a JOIN ( " +
                "SELECT columnC, cast(((min(rowid)+max(rowid))/2) as int) as midrow FROM myTemp b " +
                "GROUP BY columnC) c ON a.rowid = c.midrow")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

for the mode, I need to edit it so that it returns "no mode" where there is no mode e.g. only two different values.

```
def select_mode(conn):
    print("Mode")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT columnC, (SELECT columnF FROM myTable AS myTemp WHERE columnC = myTemp2.columnC GROUP BY columnF ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1) " +
                "FROM (SELECT DISTINCT columnC FROM myTable) AS myTemp2 ORDER BY columnC")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code for mean seems to be doing median.

Comment: Do you have to do the mode in SQL? It would be easier to fetch all the values and use `statpy` to calculate the mode.

Comment: There's also no mode if all the values have the same count. And there can be more than one mode if there are several values with the same highest frequency.

Comment: Sorry, yes. It is the median. Unfortunately, it has to be Sqlite. Good point about the mode!

Comment: @Barmar If all the values have the same count, then there are several values with the same highest frequency, so you're saying in that case there is no mode and there are multiple modes?

Comment: What should happen with NULL values for the median? What do you expect to return, if you have multimode, the first one only? I think python have better statistics function and makes the live easier.

Comment: @KellyBundy From my research, the case where ALL the values are the mode is a special case of multiple modes, and it's more common to say there's no mode. The ultimate special case is when all the values are distinct.